# How to retrieve fb's user relationship status through koala gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, koala

I ve installed the gem `koala` and `omniauth`.
In my `user` model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
def self.from_omniauth(auth)
where(auth.slice(:provider, :uid)).first_or_initialize.tap do |user|
  user.provider = auth.provider
  user.uid = auth.uid
  user.name = auth.info.name
  user.image = auth.info.image
  user.oauth_token = auth.credentials.token
  user.oauth_expires_at = Time.at(auth.credentials.expires_at)
  user.save!
end
end

def facebook
  @facebook ||= Koala::Facebook::API.new(oauth_token)
end

end
```

Ive the permission from the facebook but still i am not being able to get the relationship status?

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
@facebook.get_object('me',:fields=>"name,gender,relationship_status")
```